# Display CSV data - 1 row, several bars with d3/dimplejs

Tags: csv, d3.js, dimple.js

As an example I've got a short csv file with 1 row of data:

```
ID,AmountX,AmountY,AmountZ
1,2,1,7
```

Now my chart should display 3 bars - one is 2 units tall, one is 1 unit tall and one is 7 units tall.
But I can't get this working at all .. that's my code:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
    d3.csv("tester.csv", function (data) {
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 510, 305)
      myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["AmountX", "AmountY", "AmountZ"]);
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "AmountZ");
      myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
      myChart.addLegend(65, 10, 510, 20, "right");
      myChart.draw();
    });
  </script>
</div>
</body>
```

What do I do wrong here?

---

Changed it into JSON:

```
{
    "H1Amount": 2,
    "H2Amount": 4,
    "H3Amount": 14,
    "H4Amount": 0
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chartContainer">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);

    var x = null,
        y = null;

    d3.json("test.json", function (data) {
        var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
        myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 510, 305)

        x = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", ["H1Amount", "H2Amount", "H3Amount"]);
        x.overrideMin = 0;  
        x.overrideMax = 40;   

        myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "H1Amount");
        myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
        myChart.addLegend(65, 10, 510, 20, "right");
        myChart.draw();
    });
  </script>
</div>

</body>
```

But now I receive a white page - any idea where that comes from?
How can I debug what's going on there?

Comment: If you look at the documentation https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#data, it seems you need to have a JSON representation of your data.

Comment: Ok .. it needs to be JSON later on anyway. But now I get a white page.
How can I debug what's going on there?
Do you see an obvious problem?

Comment: I'm playing around with it and testing and trying - I can't get rid of the feeling, that the stuff is working correct but the bar is being overwritten at the same position. So only one bar shows up in the graph. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working and I guess it's about the data model.
Coming from MySQL and relational db modeling I think I simply used the wrong approach and automatically tried to normalize within PHP (where I generate the JSON).
Reading through this massive article about NoSQL data modeling: https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/ get's me a bit further in understanding how the JSON data should look like.
Thank you for your help - got deeper into d3/dimple as well through poking around a full day with this issue.

```
<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Titles</h1>
<div id="chartContainer">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 400, 300);
    var x = null,
    y = null;
    d3.json("test.json", function (error, json) {
        var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, json);
        myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 310, 205)
        x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["label"]);
        y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", ["value"]);
        myChart.addSeries("Titles",  dimple.plot.bar);
        myChart.addLegend(65, 10, 300, 20, "right");
        myChart.draw();
    });
  </script>
</div>
</body>
```

And the JSON which changed / is "denormalised" now:

```
[
    {
        "label": "H1Amount",
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "label": "H2Amount",
        "value": 4
    },
    {
        "label": "H3Amount",
        "value": 5
    },
    {
        "label": "H4Amount",
        "value": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: Great! I +1 you since you posted your solution!